# How to get rid of fatal error getId()?

Tags: category

This is my code:

```
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$categories_name = array(); $i = 0;
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    if ($_cat->getName() == "Hobby"){
        $name = "Pasionat";
    }else{
        $name = $_cat->getName();
    }
    $categories_name[$i] = $name;
    $i++;
}
```

its working perfectly when I'm on the product page, but when I'm on other page im getting  this error: **Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chester, `Mage::registry('current_product') is working only onproduct.`
that

```
if(Mage::registry('current_product')){
product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$categories_name = array(); $i = 0;
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    if ($_cat->getName() == "Hobby"){
        $name = "Pasionat";
    }else{
        $name = $_cat->getName();
    }
    $categories_name[$i] = $name;
    $i++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check, whether `Mage::registry('current_product')` contains a product, e.g.

```
is_object(Mage::registry('current_product'))
```

or

```
Mage::registry('current_product') instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
```

A better way would be (as Amit indicated) is to only add your block or code to the product detail page.

And a second tipp: Don't load every category on its on, use a collection.

Comment: yes.. you are right